# Could someone please explain each piece of code to me,I don't understand,How emplace_hint() function works and speeds up the insertion process

Tags: c++, stl

In particular line `it = s.emplace_hint(s.begin(), 1);` iterator `it` stores the position of element 1 right?,then in the next line the iterator `it` stores the position of 2,same like the above line,then when the next line executes(i.e inserting 3) `s.emplace_hint(it, 3)`,will the iterator point to the new element 3 (or) will the iterator still keeps pointing to last element inserted i.e 2?

```
// CPP program to demonstrate the 
// set::emplace_hint() function 
#include <iostream>
#include <set> 
using namespace std; 
int main() 
{ 

  set<int> s; 
  auto it = s.emplace_hint(s.begin(), 1); 

    /* stores the position of 2's insertion*/ 
    it = s.emplace_hint(it, 2); 

    /* fast step as it directly 
    starts the search step from 
    position where 3 was last inserted */
    s.emplace_hint(it, 3); 

    /* this is a slower step as 
    it starts checking from the 
    position where 3 was inserted 
    but 0 is to be inserted before 1 */
    s.emplace_hint(it, 0); 

   /* prints the set elements*/ 
    for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); it++) 
        cout << *it << " "; 

    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`emplace_hint` takes an iterator by value, and returns an iterator that "points to" the newly inserted element (or to an existing element if that value already exists in the set).  So the line

```
auto it = s.emplace_hint(s.begin(), 1);
```

adds a new element to the set containing the value `1` and sets `it` to point to that element.

The line:

```
it = s.emplace_hint(it, 2);
```

does the same thing again, only with the value `2` - the return value of `emplace_hint` is assigned to `it`.

The line:

```
s.emplace_hint(it, 3);
```

inserts a `3` into the set, but does not update the value of `it`, because you don't do the assignment.

So the value of `*it` will still be `2`.